# developing apps in c, completely

Tags: android, android-ndk

Well recently I have found ndk where I can build toolchain and compile main c file and push it with adb. But can I extend it to pakage and sign apk to upload to market. Completly in c not just‎ injecting native function to java one Thanks

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to do that. Most Android APIs are not available to C/C++. While `NativeActivity` can help you avoid *writing* any Java, you're still running as a part of a Java process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that this is possible after the introduction of Android [`NativeActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity)

This is the example Google provides on how this is done:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/native-activity

It depends though what you want to achieve because there are some Android API's that are not available in C/C++. But more and more are added check [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/).

For more NDK related staff go thourgh [Android NDK Documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk)